# How to upload a laravel project to server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

on public_html 
i want my project url
mywebesitename/plans
so i did that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKTgm.png)

inside plans is public
and inside project all laravel files
I edit my index.php code to

```
require __DIR__.'/../project/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but it does not work and just see an empty page

Comment: Did you ran `composer install`?

Comment: Read [Deploying Laravel 5 applications on shared hosting](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6)

Answer (score 0):

you need access to ssh and install composer and then upload your project anyway
the best things you can do is upload your project in [heroku](https://id.heroku.com/login) or [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/) is the best way to publish your project

you can find in youtube alot of videos   show you the way how to publish it

for mi i prefer heroku is more easy